# How to link powershell script to xaml (Visual studio for Blend)

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and Visual Studio Blend.

I have created a UI using Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio which has got text box,combobox,label.

I have a Powershell script that needs to be run according to the list items in combobox.

How do I link powershell with the XAML in VS (Blend)such that if i choose a combobox the output should be displayed in the below label I have created. Basically I need to insert Powershell inside the XAML.

I have pure powershell script that executes well , i need to execute this using a GUI.

Comment: Your question is too evasive. Provide code and be more specific. Refer to [ask]